# Insert empty record from the top or read database from bottom

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2010

I've got a problem I wasn't expect... I've got ms access database. That database includes information like: "ID" "TITLE" "ARTICLE" "AUTHOR" "DATE". To connect with database i am using OledDB Connection. I'am using repeater function. Almost everything works fine. Almost, beacuse my intention is to put the newest "article" in the top of "article list". Could You tell me, is there any option to Insert empty record from the top mdb file or read database by OledbConnection from bottom ?. Or maybe is there any option to sort information from largest index to smallest ?. Many thanks for any advise !. I'am using off course asp.net.

My code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=D:/c# database/Database1.mdb";
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Newsy", con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify your search criteria, you will get the results.

Use the following SQL statement to sort from the largest to the smallest by the ID column:

```
SELECT * FROM Newsy ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: MANY THANKS !. It works perfectly ! :). I wasn't expect that could be so easy :)